# Windows app build from phonegap not working well

Tags: cordova

I have developed application in phonegap, it's ios and android versions are working well, but for windows it shows weird UI, i.e. similar to UI when css not applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the issue. Just need to use `<!DOCTYPE html>` instead of `<html>` in html file